# Unable to use array with multi-word values

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm working on a script that requires me to have an array with a multi-word value in it.  This needs to be treated on its own.

```
all=( "test phrase" 4 11 13 )

for i in ${all@]}; do
        echo $i
done
```

I get out of it:

```
test
phrase
4
11
13
```

and I need to get:

```
test phrase
4
11
13
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need quotes:

```
for i in "${all[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: Dumb mistake on my part.  Thanks.